# Distance to next non-zero element in one-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a one-dimensional numpy array consisting of ones and zeroes, like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

For each non-zero element of the array, I want to calculate the "distance" to the next non-zero element. That is, I want to answer the question "How far away is the next non-zero element?" So the result for the above array would be:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Is there a built-in numpy function for this? And if not, what's the most efficient way to implement this in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is 2 liners. If you don't want override original `a` replace with `copy()`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])

ix = np.where(a)[0]
a[ix[:-1]] = np.diff(ix)

print(a[:-1]) # --> array([0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: There is one at the end of the output

Comment: yhaa, but this is nuance. you can always `b=a[:-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])

# create output
res = np.zeros_like(arr)

# select indices non-zero
where, = np.where(arr)

# assign the indices of the non-zero the diff
res[where[:-1]] = np.diff(where)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[0 0 0 1 3 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best answer.

`np.where` will give you the locations of the non-zero indices in increasing order.  By iterating through the result, you know the location of each 1 and the location of the following 1, and can build the result array yourself easily.  If the 1s are sparse, this is probably pretty efficient.

Let me see if I can think of something more numpy-ish.

== UPDATE ==

Ah, just came to me

```
# Find the ones in the array
temp = np.where(x)[0]
# find the difference between adjacent elements
deltas = temp[1:] - temp[:-1]
# Build the result based on these
result = np.zeros_like(x)
result[temp[:-1]] = deltas
```